# Expectations of kernel density estimate

Tags: self-study, expected-value, bias, kernel-smoothing

> Suppose $X_{1},..., X_{n}$ are independent and identically distributed according
>   to the probability density function $f$. Let
>   $${\hat{f}}_h\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{nh}\sum_{i=1}^nK\left(\frac{x-X_i}{h}\right)$$ be the
>   kernel density estimate, where $K$ is a kernel function. Assuming that
>   $$X_1,...,X_n\in{}[0,1]$$ and $$f\left(0\right)>0,$$ show that
>   $$E\left[{\hat{f}}_h\left(0\right)\right]=\frac{f\left(0\right)}{2}+O(h)$$ so that $\hat{f}_h$ is a biased estimator of $f(0)$ even when ${h\to0}$ and ${n\to\infty}$.

I know that $$E\left[{\hat{f}}_h\left(x\right)\right]= f(x)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)\mu_2 (K)+o(h^2)$$ where $\mu_2(K)$ is the second moment of kernel $K$ and the latter two terms are the bias of the estimator. However, I am
not sure how to derive $E\left[{\hat{f}}_h\left(0\right)\right]$ and get the intended formula.

Comment: I believe this question is [worth six points on the homework](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199775).

Comment: Yup and I still can't solve it.

Comment: The $1/2$ has to come from integrating $K(-x)$ from $x=0$ to $x=\infty$.  Presumably, part of your definition of a "kernel" is that this integral is indeed guaranteed to be $1/2$.